# How to call stored procedure in EF code-first approach?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework with a code-first approach. Can you provide some suggestions on how to call a stored procedure from my code?

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_GetCountry
As
Begin
    select * 
    from Country
End
```

`Homectrol.cs`:

```
 JanContext db = new JanContext ()

 public JsonResult GetCountry_sp()
 {
     string storedprocedure = "sp_GetCountry";
 }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use of EntityFramework Reverse POCO generator
[image]

edit the .tt file as below

```
 IncludeStoredProcedures = false;
```

to

```
 IncludeStoredProcedures = true;
```

This will create function in the DbContext with the name of storedprocedure u need to call this function this will call to the storedprocedure